# Confusion about articles/quantifiers: "a Tesco" VS "any Tesco" VS "Tesco"

Tags: idioms, articles, questions

Which of these ques­tions, if any, would work when po­litely ask­ing a stranger?
If more than one works, what if any dif­fer­ence is there be­tween them?

1. Ex­cuse me, is **there a Tesco** over there?
2. Ex­cuse me, is **there any Tesco** over there?
3. Ex­cuse me, is **there Tesco** over there?
4. Ex­cuse me, is **Tesco** over there?
5. (*Some­thing else I haven’t thought of?*)

Mind you, I do not want to go to just any old ge­ner­ic shop: I want
to go only to one owned by the Tesco cor­po­ra­tion. I do not care
about the size of that Tesco, whether it’s a gi­ant su­per­store
or just a lit­tle lo­cal one.

In short, how would I ask peo­ple on the street when I need to go to a shop
**named** *Tesco*?

---

### *Re­gional Note*

*Tesco* is the brand name of a very large su­per­mar­ket chain in the 
United King­dom, so you can re­place it with what­ever com­pany-name works
best for you, such as *Carre­four*, *Aldi*, *Jumbo*, *Tar­get*, *Wal­mart*,
*Kroger*, *Safe­way*, etc.

Also feel free to re­place my *over there*  at the end with any loca­tive
ad­ver­bial phrase, such as *nearby*, *around here*, *in town*, *within 
easy walk­ing dis­tance*.

Comment: Rather than ***Sainsbury's*** (unfamiliar to many learners, I'm sure), you could just as well ask about the same construction with ***shop***. The answer being you need an indefinite article (and ***any*** doesn't work with singular countable nouns in such contexts - that's ***Are** there any **shops** here?*).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have edited my question.

Comment: If you say ''Are there any shops here?" to a stranger, they'll probably say either "what shops?" or "here? Don't you have eyes?". In fact, I want to go to Tesco (or Sainsbury's), so I have to ask another question like 'Are there any Tesco shops?" or "Is there any Tesco?" or "Is there Tesco?" or "Is there a Tesco?", which was my original question above.

Comment: It's colloquial, in the UK at least, to delete  "Excuse me, is there a Tesco supermarket over there?" to "Excuse me, is there a Tesco over there?" and even to adjust to "Excuse me, is there a Tesco's over there?"

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yesterday, I asked a stranger the same question and they replied ''there is a Tesco down there'. But, why would you say "a Tesco's" instead of "a Tesco"? Its name is Tesco, not Tesco's unlike Sainsbury's

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I will ask questions on ELL next time. In the meantime, you were the one who wanted to pluralise shops, not me. My original question was 'Is there any~‘ whereas you replied with 'Are there any~’.

Comment: In terms of ('s), my question was valid, as ('s) is part of Sainsbury's name unlike Tesco. Its name is Sainsbury's not Sainsbury and its name is Tesco not Tesco's

Comment: Your point about shop is indeed correct, but it may be a useless question. Who on Earth would ask that kind of question? "Are there any shops here?". Instead of asking that question, why don't you just look for it since it is "here"? My question was about A) a specific shop  and B) "over there", not "here".

Comment: It's a type of back-formation. "Is there a butcher's down there?" "Is there a Sainsbury's down there?" so, patterning, "Is there a Tesco's ...". You'll find examples on the internet. And doubtless some people still say "Is there a Waterstone's in the mall?" even though the booksellers dropped the apostrophe from their trading name several years ago. The uninitiated and the hidebound.

Comment: I don't believe the Internet as I can't know who is native and who is not. Can you also say "Is there a hairdresser's down there?" Because, my English friend said the other day "I'm going to the hairdresser's tomorrow". Is it because he goes to the same salon? If I want to go to any salon, then would it be colloquial to ask "Is there a hairdresser's down there?"? Or is there anything else you would say?

Comment: Yes, it's fine to ask for 'a hairdresser's'. See https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/231352/why-do-you-say-go-to-the-hairdresser-instead-of-go-to-a-hairdresser

Answer (score 2):

No 1. is overwhelmingly the most natural to me (British English).

No 4. is grammatical and natural, but has a different meaning: it assumes there is a Tesco in the vicinity, and asks if it is over there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Aren't they the same?

Comment: Aren't what the same? 1 does not assume anything, 4 does.

Comment: Isn't it obvious when I say "aren't they same?"  I mean No 1 and 4,since you only mentioned No 1 and 4?

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are pointing in a specific direction, "over there" would be replaced with an expression like "near here" or "nearby." The word order can also be changed using nearby:

- Excuse me, is there a nearby Tesco?
- Excuse me, is there a Tesco nearby?

Don't ask me to explain why or what the rule is, but at least in American spoken English, you will hear an 's' added to the end of some store names. It is neither possessive nor plural to my knowledge. For example, *Carrefours*, *Aldis*, *Jumbos*, *Walmarts*, *Krogers*, but **not** *Targets* or *Safeways*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, sometimes Americans add an S and sometimes they don't? Can I leave that out and just go with "Is there a Walmart nearby?"?

Comment: You can always leave off the 's' but if you hear it in the reply ("Yes, there's a Tescos right down the street"), it likely does not mean there are plural Tescos.

Comment: In the UK any s added to the name of a retail company is possessive unless the context refers to multiple branches. For instance "I'm going to Tesco's, do you want anything?" as opposed to "There are three Tescos in this town, which one are you going to?"

Comment: I found this article. I would not call it definitive nor a trait peculiar to Pittsburgh, but it attempts address the 's' ending. The fault lies not in our stars, but in our  Sainsbury's. https://www.ydr.com/story/news/local/pennsylvania/2018/04/02/why-pittsburghers-add-s-end-words/477820002/